# Как проверить измененные файлы на сервере за определенной время?

Tags: сервер, ftp

Собственно, вопрос. И можно ли это сделать через ftp?

Comment: по FTP это можно сделать но если структура большая а соединение медленное то на это уйдет уйма времени. Надо все рекурсивно каталоги и файлы проверять и собирать информацию.

Comment: Я так понимаю, это не через FileZilla нужно делать?

Comment: Да если чисто по FTP то придется писать программу на каком то языке. Если на сервере у вас все на PHP например написано то проще PHP скриптик написать который быстро все это просчитает на сервере. Закинуть его на сервер по FTP и запустить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, почему бы нет ... Я бы раз в интервал считал бы md5 и сравнивал бы их с теми, что лежат локально (в надёжном месте) ...Total Commander md5 считает из коробки, с плагином работает хоть с FTP, хоть с SFTP.

P.S. Я всё забываю что тут уклон на программирование, уверен можно и скриптом, кому как удобнее ...

Comment: Т. е. нужно подключится по ftp, считать md5 файлов на сервере и сравнить с локальными?

Comment: Я бы решал вопрос так ... Если нет необходимости  узнать какие данные УЖЕ изменились (т.е. на текущий момент у вас нет MD5 хеша), то да - логика будет такая: Подключились по FTP // посчитали MD5 // Скопировали MD5 в <<другое место> // В нужный интервал времени подключаемся к серверу, для нового подсчёта MD5 и сравниваем их с имеющимися в <<другое месте>>.